# How to compile a linux shell script to be a standalone executable *binary* (i.e. not just e.g. chmod 755)?

Tags: scripting, binary, compilation, executable, obfuscation

I'm looking for a free open source tool-set that will compile various "classic" scripting languages, e.g. Korn Shell, ksh, csh, bash etc. as an executable -- and if the script calls other programs or executables, for them to be included in the single executable.

Reasons:

1. To obfuscate the code for delivery to a customer so as not to reveal our Intellectual Property - for delivery onto a *customer's* own machine/systems for which I have no control over what permissions I can set regarding access, so the program file has to be binary whereby the workings cannot be easily seen by viewing in a text editor or `hexdump` viewer.
2. To make a single, simply deployed program for the customer without/or a minimal amount of any external dependencies.

I would prefer something simple without the need for package manager since:

1. I can't rely on the customer's knowledge to carry out (un) packaging instructions and
2. I can't rely on the policies governing their machines regarding installing packages (and indeed from third parties).

The simplest preferred approach is to be able to compile to proper machine code a single executable that will run out of the box without any dependencies.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The solution that fully meets my needs would be SHC - a free tool, or CCsh a commercial tool. Both compile shell scripts to C, which then can be compiled using a C compiler.

Links about SHC:

- https://github.com/neurobin/shc
- http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/
- http://www.downloadplex.com/Linux/System-Utilities/Shell-Tools/Download-shc_70414.html

Links about CCsh:

- http://www.comeaucomputing.com/faqs/ccshlit.html

Comment: I'd never heard of this before, but it seems to do what the OP is asking for.  Note that it may or may not be compaitble with some features of bash or ksh, but this probabaly doesn't matter for the OP's purposes.  It also has a function to give the compiled binary an expiry date.

Comment: This is the definite answer. I been using SHC to compile my shell scripts, it's around since 2002, if I am not mistaken. SHC was made by Francisco Javier Rosales García. Although, it's a bit told, but it still works.

Comment: I recently tried this tool, SHC, and though it compiled on my dated Fedora 14 system, the resulting executables did not work correctly, they would run as if they were backgrounded, and I'd have to type `fg` to bring them to the foreground. This was the case for the most basic scripts, so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: `shc` is **not** effective obfuscation -- it's trivial to read the script contents out at runtime. `strace` or `sysdig`, or even just an appropriate scan of `/proc` will do the job of extracting the original script.

Comment: " `shc` is **not** effective obfuscation" - I would certainly not dispute that. But here, `shc` is not being used for obfuscation, but instead to provide the shell script in the form of C code - which can then be compiled to a machine-code binary executable - which provides the obfuscation in general.

Comment: I realize this was posted six years ago, but running a program compiled by `shc` still requires the shell and all called utilities to be installed. The only thing it is good for is (weak) obfuscation

Comment: It can be used for a little bit of added security; current example: I have a bash script I want to distribute as a code-signed Platypus application; to ensure at least some form of safety against bundle tampering, the shell script will verify the bundle's code signature integrity and the certificate used for code signing. With a standard shell script, you can simply edit the script and re-codesign the bundle. However, if the script is an shc-binary, it's at least a little harder. Bad thing is that shc's `-U` option for making an untraceable binary doesn't work anymore on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: PS: shc v3.9.7 fixed with support for untraceable binaries in El Capitan and later.

Answer (score 10):

You could use this: http://megastep.org/makeself/

This generates a shell script that auto-extracts a bundled tar.gz archive into the temporary directory, and then can run an arbitrary command upon extraction.

Using this tool, you can provide only one shell script to the client.

This script will then extract your *ofbsh* obfuscated scripts and binaries into /tmp, and run them transparently.

Comment: Accepted answer is to use SHC as below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423007/how-to-compile-a-linux-shell-script-to-be-a-standalone-executable-binary-i-e/6438272#6438272

Comment: @therobyouknow, the accepted answer re: SHC doesn't support bundling in other executables, which your question says is a requirement.

Comment: "SHC doesn't support bundling in other executables". I take your word for it, certainly, but it does not need to be bundled in other executables - if the output of SHC is pure C code, then this C code can be compiled, linked and built using standard tools that *do* support bundling (?)

Comment: Executable, bundle files... that sound a lot like SFX package (at 7zip, winrar). I've used shc and is great, even created a executable binary of obfsh script to try combine them.

Answer (score 5):

You can obfuscate shell scripts with [something like ofbsh](http://comp.eonworks.com/scripts/obfuscate_shell_script-20011012.html).  You won't easily bundle other programs into a single executable for unix, though.  Normally the approach for installation would be to buld a package for your platform's package manager (e.g. [rpm,](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/RPM-HOWTO/) [deb,](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) [pkg](http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/makeapackage.html)) or to provide a tarball to unravel in the appropriate directory.

If you need an executable file that unpacks the contents you might be able to use a shell archive.  Take a look at the docs for [shar(1)](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=shar) and see if that will get what you want

If you really need a scripting capability to glue multiple C programs together, take a look at the Tcl language.  It has an API that is designed to trivially wrap C programs that expect to see `argv[]` style parameters.  You can even embed the chunks of C code into a custom Tcl interpreter and glue it together with various Tcl scripts.

If you really need to make it opaque, you could encrypt the tcl scripts and wrap the whole thing in something that unencrypts the tcl scripts to a buffer and then runs the Tcl interpreter on them.  Tcl can accept scripts from a file or a `char*` buffer, so the unencrypted scripts never have to hit the file system.

Comment: I would prefer something simple without the need for package manager as 1) I can't rely on the customer's knowledge to carry out such instructions and 2) I can't rely on the policies governing their machines regarding installing packages (and indeed from third parties). The simplest preferred approach is to be able to compile to proper machine code a single executable that will run out of the box without any dependencies.

Comment: +1 For ofbsh, this might be useful in some cases. Though it might damage customer perception if the code looks unreadable, perhaps the customer may be concerned about quality issues, unless it is explained to them that the code is deliberately obfuscated so they can't understand it - which doesn't necessarily help build a relationship based on trust if we are trying to hide things from a 3rd-party, paying customer.

Comment: Better to give an executable in the first place, which eliminates any kind of hiding concerns, it is probably what the customer expects anyway and gives no indication as to how the software is implemented. No-one is going to feel that things are being hidden from them if plain executable is offered.

Answer (score 4):

[shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc)

I have modified the original [source](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/) and upgraded to a new version with some feature addition and bug fixes.
It's [here](https://github.com/neurobin/shc).

Example Usage:

```
shc -f script.sh -o binary_name
```

**script.sh** will be compiled to a binary named **binary_name**

Note that, you still need the required shell to be installed in your system to run this executable.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in Ubuntu 18.04; any updates?

Comment: @qodeninja : Please provide details on the issue page of the project. You may be doing something wrong..

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you mind if I email you? I was really excited about your project but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

[arx](https://github.com/solidsnack/arx) is a great bundler, and you may be able to integrate a obfuscator in its workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Options that are available to you:

- Write a logic in your code that, when the code is run for the first time on a box, it'll check to see if all the required packages exist. And if they do not, the code will automatically go get the packages itself and will install them...without asking to the user to do anything.  The only question the user needs to be asked is "Is it ok to proceed with the install of the aforementioned packages? (Y/N)". Anything outside of that is too much.
- Once the above code is complete (yes, i'm aware it may not be all that simple for you to code this, or may be it is, i don't know your coding capabilities), copy and paste your completed code to a site like [kinglazy.com](http://www.kinglazy.com/shell-script-encryption-kinglazy-shieldx.htm) and an actual executable file will be generated for you.

There are quite a few benefits of this particular option:

- Yes, you will be able to run the encrypted version of your script without exposing any proprietary information.
- No one can try to "view" your script, because if they do, they'll see nothing but indecipherable, encrypted jargon which wont make sense to them.
- No one can attempt to modify your script because if they do, the script will immediately become inoperable.
- No one can run a debugger on your script to see how it works.  If they do, the script will abort.
- Also, no one can create copies of your script on the same server.  If they do, it will abort and won't work. It'll only allow users to create symlinks to the original location of wherever you want the script to be.

I may be missing some things in what you asked for, but i believe the above satisfies a good portion of what you wanted.

Not sure if this works on other scripts but it certainly does for shell scripts.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the free online version of CCsh to compile a shell script into a binary:
http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryccsh/

Comment: unfortunately the domain is gone away.

Comment: That link just redirects to the home page of the website.