# Is it possible to revert compiled shell code?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have this shell script which runs correctly. However, the content of the file is...

```
3b33 8963 9a9d b0b2 98f7 8f3a cd9d 6067
b09d ae7b a351 639e 18f1 5c69 58ec 9343
512c c449 ebc0 cb64 7712 3335 2db2 b6f6
e4f7 65e6 48b1 a145 f270 1475 f062 f548
8d0e 14ec 1ca1 cd4e 6221 55fe c25b b7f8
8814 759b 11c3 3def 6b29 1fee 34fe 13fb
ee2c 3618 87af a6fc 3f5e 43b0 f885 6b6f
7aa2 9328 4f0b a2a2 f2ea cd9b 6039 b465
```

Is there anyway to reverse engineer this to normal shell code so that I can tweak the logic?

Comment: Is this the entire file? If it's not too large, can you post it as the output of `od -t x1`? Also, what are you running it on?

Comment: its part of a file :( file has 650000+ lines. running it on MacOSX

Comment: What does the code do? There might be an open source alternative.

Comment: Is that file the actual script? Does the file contain ASCII hex digits and whitespace, or is that a readable representation of a binary file? What does the `file` command say about the file? Do you know what was used to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the file size and hex dump, this is not a script anymore. It's been *compiled* into binary form by a tool [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423007/how-to-compile-a-linux-shell-script-to-be-a-standalone-executable-binary-i-e), possibly encrypted, and probably bundled with all the binaries it depends on.

If this was simply an [obfuscated script](http://www.comp.eonworks.com/scripts/obfuscate_shell_script-20011012.html), it would have been much easier to reverse. As it stands, it's still doable, but requires a lot more qualified effort. Depending on the nature of your binary, it's probably wiser (read: cheaper) to rewrite it, have the original author modify it to your needs, or write middleware that sits between this binary and your data to do additional processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your chances are slim of being able to do that. All bash to binary compilers I know of encrypt the code for the sole purpose of preventing people from reverse engineering the code.