# Is it possible to convert a bash script into an executable?

Tags: bash, converters, exe, elf

The question is simple; Is it possible to convert a bash script into an executable? and if it is, how can it be done?

Comment: But, why? Is there some system that has coreutils but not a bash shell?

Comment: Maybe you just don't want people to see what you're doing :-/. They can still disassemble the binary, but there's a lot more hassle.

Comment: There are easier ways to track what something is doing than disassembly. Run `strace` and `ltrace` and you've done half the battle. Moreover, to be fully shell-compatible, it would need to scan for external binaries for each command, and that would stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile a linux shell script to be a standalone executable \*binary\* (i.e. not just e.g. chmod 755)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423007/how-to-compile-a-linux-shell-script-to-be-a-standalone-executable-binary-i-e)

Comment: @Jahid, I'm not sure I agree that these are duplicate -- the other question there calls for dependent executables to be bundled in.

Comment: @Jahid: "if the script calls other programs or executables, for them to be included in the single executable". That's a materially relevant requirement present there and not here. (Also, a requirement the accepted answer there doesn't meet, meaning it arguably *shouldn't* be accepted). Since `shc` is limited to scripts smaller than ARG_MAX, it won't work arbitrarily large executables bundled in as with `shar`.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible, but you don't want to.

- It won't be effective obfuscation.
- It won't be smaller.
- It won't be faster.

---

### It won't be smaller

In places where support for compiling a script into a standalone executable is available, this is done by *putting a copy of the interpreter into the executable*. This is, thus, much larger than the script alone.

### It won't be faster

The execution model used by bash, unfortunately, is innately slow: Almost all functionality is provided by external commands; and simple commands' arguments, or even their names, can be modified by the result of expansion operations. This level of dynamicism makes effective compilation for performance impossible. (zsh supports a precompilation process, but the benefit is limited, mostly to the process of parsing itself).

### It won't be effective obfuscation

Take `shc`, for instance: It literally passes the script's original source as a command-line argument. Thus, that source can be read simply by reading the command-line arguments out of `/proc`, or using `strace`.

As they say, "security by obscurity is no security at all" -- anyone who's reasonably competent could trivially extract any passwords or other content obfuscated in this way.

Comment: @Jahid, strace can be blocked (by creating a prior ptrace connection); sysdig, not so much. I'd be happy to run a challenge here -- you give me an "obfuscated" binary, I'll give you back the contained script's original source. I'll even agree not to ask any of the reverse engineers I work with for help!

Comment: ...and, of course, one could also use an instrumented UML container, or a debugger attached to the kernel (trivial to do with either UML or qemu's gdb wire protocol support) to be able to track the actual syscalls invoked in a way that *can't* be blocked. But tricks that fancy aren't needed here; I'll swear them off for our challenge.

Comment: Well, I just installed `sysdig` to test, and found out the untraceable option of shc is useless. `security by obscurity is no security at all` that's an absolute truth...:D.Your explanation is enough, no challenge needed. thnks..

Comment: It's worse then that because you can see the script by examining the output of "ps -ef" ... I've made a effort to at least make it a little harder then "ps -ef" in my obash project on github.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use [shc](http://github.com/neurobin/shc) (as mentioned by Flavius Anton).**

But you need to know that this binary is not all independent. It still depends on the shell i.e if the code is written for Bash specifically and then converted with shc, it won't run without having Bash installed on the system.

### Limitations:

1. **Size:** heavily increased. `23bytes` of `test` script turned into `9.6KB` of binary.
2. **Speed:** It will run slower than the plain Bash script.
3. The size of the Bash script convertible is limited by the `_SC_ARG_MAX` system configuration parameter.
4. The binary is depended on Bash.
5. It is a code obfuscation which is rendered useless against intelligent attack.

---

## Another way is to use [Bash2py](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/):

[bash2py](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/) converts Bash source code to [python](/questions/tagged/python) source code. You can then use a tool like [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) to convert the Python source to binary which will run independently without [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Don't get too excited just yet, you will see that this is useless for actual work, at least for now (`bash2py<=3.2`).

### How To:

1. [Download and install Bash2py](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/downloads/index.html)
2. [Install cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) (or other tool)
3. write a sample script, *test*:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo works
   ```
4. convert it to python:

   ```
   bash2pyengine ./test
   ```
5. A *test.py* python script will be generated. Compile it using tools like *cx_freeze*:

   ```
   cxfreeze ./test.py
   ```
6. A binary file with lots of shared object file will be created (`dist` directory for cx_freeze). You can find a binary (named `test`) there. Run it from that directory. Note that the shared object files are the dependencies for this binary. You can port this binary as long as you take all the shared object files with it.

### Limitations:

1. **Size:** It is a two way process and in each process size is heavily increased (super heavy), specially in cxfreeze step, as it produces a lot of shared object files and also the binary file alone becomes enormous too. For the above `test` script, original size is `23bytes`, `test.py -> 38bytes`, `test (binary) -> 1.3MB`, and total `(binary and it's dependencies) -> 6.5MB!!!`
2. **Speed**: I think the Bash code will run way more faster than this.
3. All the limitations of Bash2py and freezing tool (cx_freeze or such) apply.
4. Bash2py is yet to evolve to be usable. You will see a lot of red colored text/entry in [Bash2py Manual Page](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/Bash2pyManual.html). Red colored text means *unsupported* in their context. There are lots of loosly supported features too. For example: `Array` is orange colored (now) which means "*not necessarily well supported*", actually it's not supported at all (yet `bash2py<=3.2`). So even the Bash to Python conversion is not well performed where you will have to consider the limitation of the next step (freezing) too.

### Finally:

Neither of the above is actually a real solution. And to be clear, `Bash2py` is worse than `shc`, as it doesn't support all Bash features (yet `bash2py<=3.2`) i.e you can't write codes freely and expect it to work with Bash2py.

After all this tedious effort, I can't help but agree with @Charles Duffy :

> It's possible, but you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It's a small project called "shc" (**Sh**ell **C**ompiler). You can find more info on their [Github repo](https://github.com/existz/shc-3.8.9)

I know I used it about 2 years ago and it worked fine.

Comment: I know it's unmaintained, but for just a simple bash script with old syntax this should be fine.

Comment: Yes, their name: "SHC - Bash script compiler". Why are you being so hater?

Comment: So, I read shc's source. It doesn't even **parse** bash source at all; instead, it generates an obfuscated executable that simply **calls bash**, with the original script's source as an argument. Can a program that needs a copy of bash before it'll work really be said to compile bash scripts?

Comment: Quoting from `shc`'s man page: "
shc itself is not a compiler such as cc, it rather encodes and
encrypts a shell script and generates C source code with the added expiration capability. It then uses the system compiler to compile a stripped binary
which behaves exactly like the original script. Upon execution, the compiled binary will decrypt and execute the code with the shell -c option.
Unfortunatelly, it will not give you any speed improvement as a real C program would."

Comment: ...so, the reason I'm critical boils down to false claims.

Comment: Apparently nobody claimed that they compile, except their name. And probably they did this because it sounds catchy. To me, it's obvious that it's going to be a hacky solution to this problem and I think this is a honest solution. Nobody said that you should use this in a real environment.

Comment: They do compile (from [tag:c] to binary). But the fact is, it doesn't compile shell code or convert shell code to [tag:c] , It just executes shell codes within system shell environment with a [tag:c]  coded program.

Answer (score 0):

The actual invocation of shc is the sh - c command. If the program is executing, the source code can be obtained through ps - ef. And it must be a bash shell. To address these issues, I developed [shellc](https://github.com/chenzhch/shellc), which has been open-source on GitHub, primarily through a pipeline approach similar to `cat file | bash` reaching the hidden source directory. And through  adds code obfuscation and randomly generates effective character position calculation functions to increase the complexity of disassembly and reverse engineering。