# Problem when running a shell script after it has been compiled

Tags: linux

I have created a shell script which runs perfectly when calling it from command line and giving it each argument. However, when I compile the script using my make file it ignores the case where no arguments are given and prints out nothing.

Is there something wrong with my logic for if no argument was passed in through the command line?

```
#!/bin/bash
# findName.sh
searchFile="/acct/common/CSCE215-Fall19"

if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
echo "ERROR ARGUMENT NEEDED"
exit 2
fi

grep -i $1 ${searchFile}
if [[ $? = "1" ]] ; then
  echo "$1 was not found in ${searchFile}"
fi
```

**Edit**

```
#makefile for building

findName:       main.o
    g++ -g main.o -o findName

# main
main.o:         main.cpp
        g++ -c -g main.cpp

clean:
        /bin/rm -f findName *.o

backup:
        tar cvf proj.tar * cpp Makefile *.sh readme
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string command = "./findName.sh";

    if(argc == 2)
        std::system((command + " " + argv[1]).c_str());
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "when I compile the script using my make file" please? I don't think you can compile shell scripts. Are you just calling the script from your makefile, or copying it somewhere else then calling the copied version, or something else? Can you show us the relevant part of your makefile?

Comment: Or maybe you can: here's an old answer that recommends [shc or CCsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438272/243245) for compiling bash scripts to executables. Is that what you're doing, and which are you using? Is it then just that the compiled version of your script is broken? Do you need to compile the script - can you just bundle the script that works?

Comment: Yes, please include the relevant portion of your `makefile`. Good luck.

Comment: Edited with the relevant part of my makefile, when I 'make' the findname script using this, the condition where no argument is given no longer return the proper output.

Comment: OK: your script is called findName.sh and your makefile compiles main.cpp into findName. Unless main.cpp is generated from findName.sh (and I can't see it here) then these are two separate things. You are not, as far as I can see, compiling your bash script - you do include it in the backup .tar, but you don't do anything else to it in the makefile. After you've run `make` are you running `./findName` or `./findName.sh`? Is the problem that findName, the one you compile from main.cpp, doesn't have the command line warning? Can you check that main.cpp generates the warning?

Comment: Updated with main.cpp, i am running make with ./findName. When running ./findName.sh the program runs corectly, I am running into problems when running make and then ./findName

Comment: The `argc == 2` check in your main.cpp checks you have supplied exactly one argument, and it's only then that you call your shell script. So if you want an error from main.cpp when no arguments are supplied then you'll either have to add code to do that there or add another case that calls your shell script without any arguments if argc < 2. As it stands if you call main.cpp without any arguments then it will do nothing, yes.